# How to persist settings for default audio output on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: sound, microphone, settings, 21.04, speakers

I have Ubuntu 21.04 running.

I always need to change the audio output settings from "Analog Out" (which has no sound) to "Speakers" (works well).

The same problem occurs with the audio input ("Analog input" does not work, but "Internal microphone" does).

How to persist these changes?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem - pulseaudio was defaulting to my USB headset, but I want sound to come to my speakers by default and I'll switch to the headset using video conferencing software if I'm on a call.

I ran `pactl list short sinks` to find out which 'sinks' (i.e. audio output devices) are available. The output looked like this:

```
$ pactl list short sinks
1   alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.4.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
7   alsa_output.pci-0000_07_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

The first of these, which the list has as `RUNNING`, is my USB headset. The one I want is the second. If I run `pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.4.analog-stereo` this makes the right device active, but this is just like changing the option in the 'Sound' settings menu.

To make the change persistent through rebooting, I edited `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and added `set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.4.analog-stereo` to the bottom of the file (i.e. the same as the command above but missing off the `pactl` from the front).

So work out which device you want to switch to, run `pactl set-default-sink device` to check you have this right, then add `set-default-sink device` to the bottom of `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

For input devices, the equivalent commands are `pactl list short sources` and `pactl set-default-source`.